# Should the stackoverflow tag excerpt be altered to guide people to SO/MSO if applicable?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags, meta

I just noticed that Meta has a [stackoverflow](/questions/tagged/stackoverflow) tag.

First, I wanted to suggest to delete it, but then I thought of a useful application for it (also, it has 5.8K questions, so probably a little hard to delete).

Should the tag excerpt be altered so it guides people not understanding the difference between Meta and MSO to post their question on the right Meta?

If so, what should it contain?

> Are you posting on the right site? If you have **programming
>   questions**, post them on https://stackoverflow.com/. Questions about **how
>   Stack Overflow works**, but not related to the entire SE network should
>   be asked on https://meta.stackoverflow.com/.

Comment: I'd think we'd want to move all the questions over to MSO, *then* have the tag removed, but that's just me.  I don't think that's the process that's actually being done, for some reason.

Comment: I thought of it too, but is seems to me that these questions might be more appropriate for Meta than MSO.